# Is deleting a question that is a duplicate of more than one question the exception to the rule?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-delete

I noticed that some questions, which are closed as duplicate of more than a question, are voted to be deleted.

Is that an exception to the *rule* of not deleting duplicates? Is there a specific schema with deleting duplicates, in that case?